# How to use MultiBlocProvider in specific level in flutter tree widget?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I want to use `MultiBlocProvider` as shown below.

[image: How to use MultiBlocProvider in specific level in flutter tree widget ?]

How to use MultiBlocProvider in specific level in flutter tree widget ?

In other words, when we use MultiBlocProvideron `top` of `MaterialApp`, there is no problem. But according to the code below, this item gets an error.

example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
      switch (settings.name) {
        case "/":
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
                    BlocProvider(
                      create: (_) => CounterBloc(),
                    )
                  ], child: const GroupA()),
              settings: settings);
        case "/ScopeA":
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => const ScopeA(), settings: settings);
        default:
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => const Text("ERROR"), settings: settings);
      }
    },
  ));
}

class GroupA extends StatelessWidget {
  const GroupA({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Group A:')),
      body: Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/ScopeA'),
            child: const Text("Go To Scope A")),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScopeA extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScopeA({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Scope A:')),
      body: Center(
        child: BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, int>(
          builder: (context, count) {
            return Text(
              '$count',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

abstract class CounterEvent {}

class CounterIncrementPressed extends CounterEvent {}

class CounterDecrementPressed extends CounterEvent {}

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, int> {
  CounterBloc() : super(0) {
    on<CounterIncrementPressed>((event, emit) => emit(state + 1));
    on<CounterDecrementPressed>((event, emit) => emit(state - 1));
  }
}
```

i using below version :
flutter_bloc : `8.1.2`
bloc : `8.1.1`

error:

> Error: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.

Answer (score 0):

You're misleading the concept behind passing blocs through sub-tree and through `Navigator` widgets.

Basically, the `MultiBlocProvider`or `BlocProvider` make a bloc accessible in all the subtrees, so the bloc will be available only in `GroupA`'s subtree of widgets, by calling `Navigator.pushNamed()`, what does happen is that another separated sub-tree will be put in the `Navigator` child, so at this point the `GroupA` and `ScopeA` will not be in the same widget-tree, even if it seems to when you see a page route is set on top of other's on the Flutter UI, I can represent it like this:

```
               -> MultiBlocProvider -> GroupA 
Navigator => | 
               -> ScopeA
```

and as you conclude, the bloc that is available inside the `GroupA` will not be available in `ScopeA`, until you pass it in somehow, like using `BlocProvider.value()`:

```
   case "/ScopeA":
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
               return BlocProvider.value(
                 value: context.read<CounterBloc>(),
                 child: const ScopeA(),
               );  
              },
            settings: settings,
          );
```

or by making the bloc accessible through the whole app, so you will have a Flutter tree like this:

```
                                    -> GroupA 
MultiBlocProvider -> Navigator => | 
                                    -> ScopeA
```